# nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "PERSON" already exists; SQL statement:

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I've tried to create JPA small demo project, I faced this problem

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personJdbcDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/D:/Learning/c5/springframework/target/classes/schema.sql]: create table person ( ID integer not null, PERSON_NAME varchar(255) not null, LOCATION varchar(255), BIRTH_DATE timestamp, primary key(ID) ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "PERSON" already exists; SQL statement:
> create table person ( ID integer not null, PERSON_NAME varchar(255) not null, LOCATION varchar(255), BIRTH_DATE timestamp, primary key(ID) ) [42101-214]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]

**Below my config**

I made schema.sql for my H2 in the memory database.

src/main/resources/schema.sql

```
create table person
(
    ID integer not null,
    PERSON_NAME varchar(255) not null,
    LOCATION varchar(255),
    BIRTH_DATE timestamp,
    primary key(ID)
);

INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, PERSON_NAME, LOCATION, BIRTH_DATE )
VALUES(1,  'Fazal', 'Peshawar',NOW());
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, PERSON_NAME, LOCATION, BIRTH_DATE )
VALUES(2,  'Haroon', 'Islamabad',NOW());
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, PERSON_NAME, LOCATION, BIRTH_DATE )
VALUES(3,  'Khan', 'Lahore',NOW());
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, PERSON_NAME, LOCATION, BIRTH_DATE )
VALUES(4,  'Khan', 'Islamabad',NOW());
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoJPAApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoJPAApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoJPAApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("User id 1 -> {}", personRepository.findById(1));
    }
}
```

Repository Class

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public Person findById(int id){
        return entityManager.find(Person.class, id);
    }
}
```

enitity class, here i use lombok

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "person_name")
    private String personName;
    @Column(name = "location")
    private String location;
    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    private Date birthDate;
}
```

**Could someone find what's wrong with my project? Really appreciate your help.**

I run the problem and faced this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small error that i face when i run this program.

The error said "Table 'PERSON' already exists" because we are already creating in **schema.sql**.

Spring boot auto configuration knows that we are using in-memory database H2 and that JPA is in the classpath. It also knows that I'm defining entities as well because i put **@Entity** in the Person class. So what it does is triggers schema update which is the hibernating feature, it automatically creates this schema for us.

so from now on, i don't need to define CREATE TABLE in **schema.sql**

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, PERSON_NAME, LOCATION, BIRTH_DATE )
VALUES(1,  'Fazal', 'Peshawar',NOW());
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, PERSON_NAME, LOCATION, BIRTH_DATE )
VALUES(2,  'Haroon', 'Islamabad',NOW());
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, PERSON_NAME, LOCATION, BIRTH_DATE )
VALUES(3,  'Khan', 'Lahore',NOW());
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, PERSON_NAME, LOCATION, BIRTH_DATE )
VALUES(4,  'Khan', 'Islamabad',NOW());
```

i remove the CREATE TABLE PERSON from *src/main/resources/schema.sql* because the table would be created for me by schema update.

**Schema update is triggered by a spring boot auto configuration and is one of the hibernate features.**